# Cloud foundry app deployment automation using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

How to automate the deployment of cloud foundry app using nodejs. Which library or module should i use ?? As we are manually deploying the node app in ibm bluemix using cf commands as follows.

- cf
- cf login -u **usermail** -o **organisation** -s **space**
- API endpoint *******
- password *******
- cf apps // to list the apps
- cf push **app-name** // to push the code from my local cmd

Comment: Define automation and make the question more specific

Comment: Google is your friend: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cf-nodejs-client

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wish to do as automation. you can put these commands in a script and then use any CI tool. Also, IBM has UrbanDeploy product which has cloudfoundry plugins which you can use to automate deployment.